# Review Audits: dealing with false negatives and consequences thereof?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I just reviewed a late answer, and it was one of the low quality answers. While it was not a perfect answer it was still correct. However the answer was already removed, so I cannot comment on it. Is there a way to justify my "no action needed" on such kind of answers?

Or put it another way, do I need to care about failed audits in the review system?

[Node not recognized although successfully installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129505/node-not-recognized-although-successfully-installed/25801210#25801210)

Comment: For, the second question, if you care about not getting banned from reviewing, you do need to care about failed audits.

Comment: @user000001 well, I don't want to be banned from that function (even when it is not really paying of to help out in this category). I guess there is some secret threshold. If that is high enough I would not botter to get that audit rectified, but if it is low (and unlimited time) I would rather have an option to get the review re-reviewed.

Comment: With late answers, if you are not sure if the answer is good/bad, one could click on the link in the question below. If the question you are asked to review is not on the page you linked to then you should downvote/flag the late answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no appeal of review audits. What is done is done.

> do I need to care about failed audits in the review system?

If you are reviewing carefully, an occasional failed audit is of no real consequence and should not discourage you from reviewing. For more, see [answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213876/).

"Peeking behind the curtain" is a common reason for failed audits: reviewer finds out in some way that the post was already deleted, and decides that no action is needed. Just realize that the system would not ask you to review a deleted post just for the fun of it. If it's already deleted, you are being audited: your reaction is being evaluated. React as you would if the review was  real.

All "known bad" audit answers are already deleted; *this is how they are known to be bad*.  Many of "known" bad questions are already deleted, too; others are closed.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your "no real consequence" - I hadn't failed an audit in months, I've only failed a small handful ever, and I failed one last week and got review-banned for 2 days for it. (It *was* kind of on the fence, so I didn't bother complaining about it.)

Unless of course you want to argue that being review-banned for a couple days is "no real consequence", which I suppose is true enough, it doesn't prevent you from doing anything important for your own benefit, just for the site's. :p

Comment: Yes, being banned isn't something to worry about, either. "The message you see upon being banned suggests that perhaps you need a break, and *that really is the intent*"

Comment: I recently had to audit an answer that had no accompanying question ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes there's no black and white case. An answer can be low quality because it doesn't really answer the question, it just provides some brief technical detail or statement with no explanation given, such as "I tried to do x and it solved the problem for me". Such brief statements are really just comments, if there is no explanation why.

In order to tell whether such brief statements are acceptable answers or just a comment that doesn't answer the question, you might need to know the technical stuff that the question and answer is about. If you aren't certain or if you suspect that you need to have specific knowledge about the topic to tell, the "skip" button should be used.

In your specific case, the answer was on-topic and attempted to answer the question, so it might have been a valid answer. It seems that someone with more knowledge of the topic thought that the answer was so poor that it needed to be removed.

Note that the review audit system is broken, so you will sometimes get review audits where the post is just fine, yet the audit thought they were not.

Comment: The answer was also correct, but anyway, thanks for the discussion. I decided not to worry :)