# No action needed and Skip buttons

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

Today is the first time I have failed an automatic audit.

There was a link only answer. The interface offered only two options, `No action needed` and `Skip`. I wanted to flag the question, but it didn't exist anymore, so I have chosen `No action needed` and that's how I failed the test.

Shouldn't always be a way to flag a question/answer when reviewing?

**Example of first post**

The following question doesn't exist anymore(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015670/libsvm-training-issues). What option should one choose?

[image: Review First Posts]

Comment: If you wanted to flag a post and couldn't why would you say there was nothing wrong with it?

Comment: I didn't choose an option that said "nothing is wrong with the post". I thought no action was needed since the post was deleted.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I wouldn't read it that way but hadn't considered others might. If it were changed to "Looks okay" (for instance) would you have still clicked on it? P.S. what queue/review was this?

Comment: I wouldn't have clicked it. I believe it was the `First Posts` section.

Comment: This is a typical reason for failed audits among new reviewers; see [my explanation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272837/).

Comment: "React as you would if the review was real." - The only way to react was to skip the review?

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't a "flag" link under the answer in the review interface? I believe the expected response for a link-only answer audit is to flag the answer as "is not an answer".

Comment: I couldn't access any flag option because the answer was deleted. In the `First Posts` queue there is also a grey `I'm Done` button, but it seems to be disabled most of the time. Unfortunately I don't have the link to the review.

Comment: @Seitaridis the point I think Andrew is trying to make is before you found the answer was deleted, was the flag button there?  Review audits are frequently deleted posts, but they appear normal.  Trying to flag should pass the audit.  So how did you discover the answer was deleted

Comment: Additionally, the `I'm Done` button will be grayed out until you take some action on the post.  That is why the "No Action Needed" button is there... it basically means "the post is ok, it doesn't deserve an upvote or downvote but doesn't need closed or flagged".

Comment: There was no flag button there before I found out that the answer was deleted. Because there was no flag button in the review, I have opened another tab to look at the question where the answer was posted and to flag it as link-only. I couldn't because the answer didn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was wrong. There wasn't any flag button, but there is a flag link on each question/answer. When I review, most of the time I use the top buttons. In that situation I should have used the flag link. Indeed, the `I'm Done` button becomes active after flagging the post.

Comment: I struggled with this, not very intuitive

Comment: I believe that the purpose of this is to emphasize that, in the First Posts queue, you are encouraged to take any (and as many) action(s) as needed to improve the post and thus the buttons at the top are only the ones used for progressing through the queue. Other queues only allow you to take one action and those actions are restricted to the buttons provided.